# How to connect database using ADO.Net?

Tags: .net, asp.net, ado.net

In ASP.NET with VS 2008, I want to connect to a Microsoft SQL Server using ADO.Net
This is the my connection string:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\JavaScript\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True
```

Here's my code:

```
OleDbConnection ocon = new OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB;"+"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;"+"AttachDbFilename=E:\JavaScript\App_Data\Database.mdf;"+"Integrated Security=True;"+"User Instance=True");
OleDbCommand ocom=new OleDbCommand();
OleDbDataAdapter oda=new OleDbDataAdapter();


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ocon.Open();
    ocom.CommandText = "StoredProcedure1";
    ocom.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    ocom.Connection = ocon;
    ocom.ExecuteReader();
    ocon.Close();
}
```

When I run this, the error occurs in the connection string.
So how to connect the sqlserver database Using ADO.net?

Comment: what is the exact error string you get

Answer (score 3):

Use `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection`, as well as SqlCommand and the rest, instead of the OleDb classes. Also be sure you use `using` blocks to ensure that your connection is returned to the connection pool when you're done with it. Also, Tom's suggestion of using connectionstrings.com to figure out the proper connection string for a SqlConnection object is a good one.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.CommandText = "StoredProcedure1";
        conn.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                // do stuff with the current row
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Connectionstrings.com](http://connectionstrings.com) is a great resource when you need help with the various options for all sorts of database connections.