# Populate MVC C# dropdown list from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I'm trying to populate my dropdown list with some data pulled from SQL server. 
I'm new to MVC C# and don't know how to do it.

```
Table name GroupList
fields: 
GroupListId   GroupName   
1              px
2              dx
3              NPI
```

In my controller:

```
public ActionResult Group()
{
    return View();
}
```

In my model:

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetGroupList { get; set; }
public int SelectedGroupID { get; set; }

// How I can pull my data from the database?
```

In my view:

```
<select id="GroupDropdownListID" name="GroupList">
    <option value="" selected>None Selected</option>
    @foreach (var data in Model.GetGroupList)
    {
        <option value="@data.Value">@data.Text</option>
    }
 </select>
```

Comment: Your title doesn't really reflect your question here. Your real question is in a small comment inside a code bloc. I suggest editing the title and make the question more clear

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to get data from a SQL database so this question is quite vague. Rather than not offer anything or downvoting this, I'd like to suggest you take a look at a few resources that might lead you in a positive direction:

It sounds like you have an existing database so I might suggest you start with basic ADO.Net: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ado-net-code-examples
or [How to connect database using ADO.Net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620472/how-to-connect-database-using-ado-net)

If you have a new database you could look into an ORM like...
Entity Framework: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/get-started
Dapper: https://medium.com/dapper-net/get-started-with-dapper-net-591592c335aa